# Google Earth Engine if..else not working

Tags: google, if-else

I am developing this code on Google Earth Engine platform. I want to compare simple code where i change `StMonth (2000)` from `StMonth=1` than by month advance next month will be Feb=2,
But when i change StMonth=12, by month advance StMonth changes to 1 and tEnDate changes from 2000 to 2001.
Than i comapred if year is changed than it shows error.
The output should be that when EndYear==2000, output print the "End Year same"
Or when Endyear is 2001, output of EnYear==2000 condition will be "End Year Different"
But, instead i getting the same conditional output either first sentence (...same,) or second sentange (...different),

```
var CHIRPS = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY");
var StYear = 2000;var StMonth = 1;
var EnYear = 2002;var EnMonth= 12;
var PredYear=2003;var PredMonth=1;
var logic=0;
var BandName="precipitation";
var StDate=ee.Date.fromYMD(StYear,StMonth,1);
var EnDate=ee.Date.fromYMD(EnYear,EnMonth,1);

print('St Date=',StDate,'to ',EnDate);

var PrepCollection=ee.ImageCollection([])
var tEnDate=StDate.advance(1,'month');
var EndYear=tEnDate.get('year')
print('tEndate=',tEnDate)
print('EndYear=',EndYear)
print('Compare EndYear,',EndYear,'==2000-> ',EndYear.eq(2000))
var logic=ee.Number(EndYear).eq(2000);
if(ee.Number(logic)==1){
  print('End Year Same')
}
else
{
  print('End Year Diff')
}
```